# ubuntu mic records noise and no voice

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, microphone, audio-recording

On making calls or recording voice the Mic keeps producing noisy and scratchy sounds. What I attempted to do is running `alsamixer`, then find both Mic boost and internal Mic boost is set to 0, after changing them and running `pulseaudio -k` they go back to 0 again.

Comment: Did you make sure it is not a hardware problem?

Comment: @danzel Yes I'm sure. I have a dual boot, and it works OK on my windows machine.

Comment: `pulseaudio -k` kills Pulseaudio, but Pulseaudio usually restarts automatically. `pactl list short modules` will probably show module-device-restore and module-card-restore, which would reset audio levels from Pulseaudio. I do not understand why you use command to restart Pulseaudio. Do you use command `sudo alsactl store` to save ALSA changes?